# Display data based on id from 2 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Honestly i dont quite understand what the title of my problem, so i'll explain it. I have 2 tables, 1. user table, 2. creation.

User table: id_users, name, gender

Creation: id_creation, user_id, type, year

In creation table, the user_id can have more than 1 id_users, example in 1 row of data:

id_creation: 1. user_id: 1,2,3. type: book. year: 2018.

Then i want to show the creation table with the user table like:

id_creation: 1. user_id: john, mike, susan. type: book. year: 2018

I already use the in_array function but the result is nothing.

my model:

```
function get_all()
{
  $this->db->join('users', 'creation.user_id = users.id_users');
  return $this->db->get('creation')->result();
}
```

any help will so appreciate

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no error showed

Comment: Can you show you both table data in an image?

Comment: you should not store more than one value in the user_id column. maybe "many-to-many" relationship is what you need here

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be solved with find_in_set function. it'll give you 3 rows. also see following use cases which might generate error

case 1:
1 ,2 ,3 -> wrong,
case 2:
1,2,3   -> Right,
case 3:
1, 2, 3 -> Wrong,

just don't give space between values

```
function get_all()
{
  $this->db->join('users', 'find_in_set(creation.user_id , users.id_users'),'INNER JOIN');
  return $this->db->get('creation')->result();
}
```